# Samsung Galaxy S3 SCH-I535, rooted, won't switch over to T-Mobile

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, t-mobile

Recently, I changed carriers from Verizon to T-Mobile. However, when I inserted my T-Mobile SIM card into my phone and rebooted, the status is always "Searching for Service" (not just for data, NOTHING works). I've looked on Android forums and they all have instructions for turning the SCH-I535 into a world phone, but that's not what I want. I just want to switch to T-Mobile (do I need to have a "world phone" to do this?)

I've installed APN Manager and tried to change APNs, but entering the details found here

The phone is rooted and not on a stock TouchWiz ROM (I'm using Paranoid Android, a JB ROM)

Why won't my phone recognize the T-Mobile SIM?

Comment: If you got the phone from Verizon, likely it's SIM-locked. You need an unlock code to use it with SIM cards from another carrier.

Comment: I don't think that's true. I put a T-Mobile SIM into someone else's phone just now too and theirs worked immediately, barring data (nonroot TouchWiz). Honestly, at this point I don't mind not having mobile data, I just want to call and text

Comment: @DanHulme Even if it's been rooted?

Comment: @AnotherUser Yes, even if it's been rooted. See the [tag:sim-unlocking] tag wiki for more about SIM lock.

Answer (score 1):

SCH-I535 is not a GSM phone so will not work with any 2G or 3G T-Mobile tower. Also that phone only supports LTE frequencies of 700 MHz & 1900 MHz, neither of which are bands that T-Mobile use to any significant degree. Instead T-Mobile uses 1700 & 2100 MHz.

T-Mobile is however in the process of rolling out 700 MHz & 1900 MHz, so you might get data in the near future however you will not generally be able to make calls as that is currently handled by the 3G networks. And even where VoLTE is available this phone will may not have the software update to support it.

**Update:** Despite not being listed in the specs of [Samsung's](http://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/cell-phones/SCH-I535MBBVZW) website, nor [GSM Area](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_s_iii_cdma-4799.php), or [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S_III) SCH-I535 does infact support GSM beyond LTE. It appears that Verizon pushed out an update with 4.1.2 Jelly Bean which enabled support for GPRS/EDGE/GSM 850/900/1800/1900 MHz and HSPA/UMTS 2100 MHz (band 1). T-Mobiles 3G support requires AWS-1700/2100 (band 4), however they do support 1900 MHz for GSM/EDGE 2G service.

So you can get EDGE but not HSPA, although you may soon get LTE depending on T-Mobiles rollout.

Comment: How does this explain the other SCH-I535 (someone I know) that changed from verizon SIM to t-mobile SIM today which works for calling/texting but not data?

Comment: Well if the below data is correct, SGH-I535 should not work on T-Mobile. There are GSM versions of the Galaxy S3, are you 100% sure the other phone was SGH-I535 not the GSM SGH-I747?

http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_s_iii_cdma-4799.php

Comment: I'm not 100% sure it was a SGH because I said it was a SCH, but I am 100% sure of that

Comment: Yes sorry this is a typo I copied off GSM Arena, the C is for CDMA and the G is for GSM, the frequency information however agrees with below. So it is truly baffling how you managed to get a CDMA phone working on a GSM network. Unless you are in an area where T-Mobile already has 700 MHz or 1900 MHz LTE and are using VoLTE.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S_III#Model_variants

Comment: So yer if you have 700 MHz or 1900 MHz LTE available then most likely the handset is locked, even though it is rooted the phone can still be locked to Verizon so you could try call them to get the unlock code.

Comment: @itdoesntwork Have you got it working?

Comment: yes, I have. The main problem was the custom rom. I flashed a stock rom via Odin and the problem resolved itself when I switched over to GSM. However, I can only get data on Edge, but that's a different issue.

Comment: @itdoesntwork Sorry about the misinformation my sources were out of date, after further digging I can see global GSM support was added by Verizon and I have updated the post to reflect this.